# Chromedriver session Error.Session not created:Chrome version must be>= 60.0.3112.0(chromedriver=2.33.506092,platform=Linux 4.10.0-42-genericx86_64)

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium, hybrid-mobile-app

My app is the Hybrid App (not the Native App).So to change the context from native to Hybrid,I have created the instance of Android driver.After three swaps,I want change the context.So I used
     driver.context(contextList.get(1));
As far as I know ,the error is coming because of the above line only.Any alternative to this??

```
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class App {

    @Test
    public void test_1() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DesiredCapabilities capa = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capa.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);


        capa.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "DeviceID");
        capa.setCapability("udid", "DeviceID");
        capa.setCapability("appPackage", "packagenamegiven");
        capa.setCapability("appActivity", "packagenamegiven.MainActivity");

        AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capa);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement me = driver.findElement(By.className("android.webkit.WebView"));
        int wide = me.getSize().width;
        int hgt = me.getSize().height;

        int startx = (int) (wide * (0.8));
        int endx = (int) (wide * (0.2));
        int starty = hgt / 2;
        int endy = hgt / 2;

        driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, 1000);
        // 2nd Screen

        me = driver.findElement(By.className("android.webkit.WebView"));
        wide = me.getSize().width;
        hgt = me.getSize().height;

        startx = (int) (wide * (0.8));
        endx = (int) (wide * (0.2));
        starty = hgt / 2;
        endy = hgt / 2;


        driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, 1000);

        // 3rd Screen

        me = driver.findElement(By.className("android.webkit.WebView"));
        wide = me.getSize().width;
        hgt = me.getSize().height;

        startx = (int) (wide * (0.8));
        endx = (int) (wide * (0.2));
        starty = hgt / 2;
        endy = hgt / 2;
        driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, 1000);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Set<String> allContexts = driver.getContextHandles();

        allContexts.stream().forEach(x -> System.out.println(x));
    ArrayList<String> contextList = (ArrayList<String>) allContexts.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
        driver.context(contextList.get(1));
        System.out.println("Present context is :"+driver.getContext());

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.quit();
        System.out.println("Test is Successful");

    }

}
```

Output/Exception coming is

> NATIVE_APP WEBVIEW_packagenamegiven FAILED: test_1
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error
>   occurred while processing the command. Original error: Failed to
>   start Chromedriver session: A new session could not be created.
>   (Original error: session not created exception: Chrome version must be
>
> > = 60.0.3112.0
> >           (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux
> >     4.10.0-42-generic x86_64)) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
> >         Command duration or timeout: 4.06 seconds
> >         Build info: version: '2.50.1', revision: 'd7fc91b29de65b790abb01f3ac5f7ea2191c88a7', time: '2016-01-29
> >     11:11:26'
> >         System info: host: 'about-system-info', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.10.0-42-generic',
> >     java.version: '1.8.0_131'
> >         Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
> >         Capabilities [{appPackage=packagename, deviceScreenSize=720x1280, networkConnectionEnabled=true, warnings={}, databaseEnabled=false,
> >     deviceName=EP732287GB, platform=LINUX, deviceUDID=EP732287GB,
> >     appActivity=packagename.MainActivity, desired={appPackage=packagename,
> >     appActivity=packagename.MainActivity, platformName=Android,
> >     udid=deviceId, deviceName=DeviceId}, platformVersion=5.0.2,
> >     webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false,
> >     takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, deviceModel=C5502,
> >     platformName=Android, udid=deviceId, deviceManufacturer=Sony}]
> >         Session ID: 02bd3479-850b-4cfb-a541-360a2117cf0f
> >           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> >           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> >           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> >           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
> >           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
> >           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
> >           at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
> >           at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
> >           at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
> >           at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.context(AppiumDriver.java:546)
> >           at package_name.App.test_1(App.java:83)
> >           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> >           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> >           at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
> >           at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
> >           at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
> >           at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
> >           at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
> >           at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
> >           at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
> >           at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
> >           at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
> >           at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
> >           at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
> >           at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
> >           at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
> >           at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
> >           at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
> >           at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
> >           at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
> >           at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
> >           at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
> >           at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

```
===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it's an hybrid application, it also required matching `chromedrive.exe` inside `appium` and chrome installed in mobile device(since chrome is default browser in android).

So try to have updated chrome browser in mobile device(if not updated) and also use the latest `chromedriver.exe` inside `appium`( `C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-chromedriver\chromedriver\win\`)

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: I am running it on Ubuntu and I will update the chromedriver and let you know about the status.

Comment: @Nikhil_Coder Hope your problem will solve If you have updated version of chromedriver.exe inside appium folder and update chrome browser in your mobile device

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Failed to start Chromedriver session: A new session could not be created. (Original error: session not created exception: Chrome version must be >= 60.0.3112.0
```

Your main issue is the **version compatibility** among the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using **`chromedriver=2.33`**
- Release Notes of [**`chromedriver=2.33`**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> **`Supports Chrome v60-62`**

- You are using **`Chrome Browser`** version is unknown to us but possibly below *v60.x*. The error clearly confirms by the log `Chrome version must be >= 60.0.3112.0`
- You are using **`Selenium Version 2.50.1`** (released *time: '2016-01-29 11:11:26'*) which is a bit older.
- Your **`JDK version`** is **`1.8.0_131`** which is also a bit older.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *chromedriver* version (*v2.33*) and the matching requirement i.e. *Chrome v60-62*

### Solution

- Upgrade `JDK` to  recent levels **`JDK Version 8 Update 151`**.
- Upgrade `Selenium` to  current levels **`Version 3.8.1`**.
- Upgrade `ChromeDriver` to  **`ChromeDriver v2.35`** level.
- Keep `Chrome Browser` to  **`v64.x`** levels. ([*as per ChromeDriver v2.35 release notes*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt))
- Incase your *Chrome Browser* base version is older, try to uninstall *Chrome Browser* through [Revo Uninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install the required recent GA released version of the *Chrome Browser* .
- Clear the *Browser Cache* before your *Test Excution* .
- Run [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool before and after execution of your *Test Suites* .
- Execute your `Test`.

Comment: My chrome browser version is above 60 and yaa I will update the  stuff and let you know about the result

Comment: Added 3 more steps. Let me know the status.

Comment: how to update the chrome driver in ubuntu 17.04. I tried many steps but still it is not updating.Can you please update the same